# Can I SSH into a computer using Landscape?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, landscape

I have a couple of computers that I manage using [Canonical Landscape.](http://landscape.canonical.com)

Both of them are behind routers and in different cities so I can't easily SSH into them using openssh. They're running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Edition. Can I use Landscape to SSH into the computers?

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can use landscape to run commands on the box. You could (for example) run whatever you wanted to run via ssh, but as a script.

Another option would be to setup a reverse SSH tunnel via that script system.

So you could create a script to run on the landscape managed host which ssh'ed back to your home machine or some other publicly accessible IP:-

```
ssh -R2222:localhost:22 username@homeserver.example.com
```

You'd need an ssh key to already be generated without a pass-phrase on the remote machine and place the public part on 'homeserver' in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys as a pre-requisite to doing this.

Once that ssh tunnel is setup, you should be able to (on homeserver.example.com):-

```
ssh -P 2222 username@localhost
```

This will redirect ssh (on port 2222) from homeserver.example.com to port 22 on the remote host.

Comment: I get that I can run commands as scripts, but (excuse my noobish), how do you deal with feedback that those commands give? For example, running sudo apt-get install foo will prompt for a "Y/n" response after it's run.

Comment: For apt-get it has a "-y" option to make it just auto answer "yes" to those prompts. Other commands can have "foo < echo 'yes'" fudged into them. Each command is different though of course.

Answer (score 2):

You currently cannot use Landscape as a remote console proxy, but it is one of the most-requested features, so it is in active consideration.  If you want to provide more information on what your use case would be, that would be helpful -- I am gathering, getting around non-routable IPs and firewall(s) is your need?

Comment: The use case is clear, it's illogical why Canonical is dragging their feet (since 2012!) on this one seeing as Landscape is an expensive paid service for small businesses.
Small businesses, with clients in remote locations, with ISP's who do not allow access to their router config for NAT  need a way to provide their customers instant functional support via SSH and XVNC. Teamviewer is not an option due to the prohibitive license of 700 euro per client and is considered unsafe(man in the middle) for businesses.
It would be enough just to have an Open Reverse SSH tunnel button in Landscape.

Comment: @DamiönlaBagh actually, multiple use cases are clear, which is why I was asking (back in 2012) for more details to see which one was being requested here. I am no longer in charge of Landscape, and you will need to contact the new PM if you want to lobby for this feature.

Comment: I saw «after» my comment that you had a new job since your post. I have a paid support contract with Canonical and have raised the issue there. They don't seem too keen on solving it though. Best of luck to you at RedHat!